# Exporting data from Excel sheet into XML file

Tags: xml, excel

I am dealing with a large number of records. I have around 5,50,000 records in an excel sheet. I need to export that data in an XML file. I tried using the inbuilt functions in Excel but it has a limitation. A max of only 65,000 records can be exported into XML file using Excel.
Can you please suggest something on how can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you use `csv` as file format ? (it is only raw text?) If yes, then you could possibly parse and transform it through a bash / cmd script and treating it like a text file

Comment: Hi flafouxm I am using csv only as a file format. How can I parse and transform it using a cmd script? You mean I have to write a Java code and run it in cmd?

Comment: I remember now that I used this tool : https://code.google.com/p/xml2csv-conv/

Comment: Okay, thanks. But this tool is to create xml to csv. Are you aware of any tool that converts csv to xml?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your file is saved in the XLSX format.
2. In File Explorer, right click the XLSX file > Unzip.
3. Browse unzipped contents, you should see an XML file with your data. In my version of Excel, the data is in the `\xl\worksheets` folder.